# Why is this JavaScript code entering a for loop after the boolean expression is no longer true?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

**Edit:** This turned out to be a case of Firebug incorrectly stepping through the code, while my bug was elsewhere. A coworker who has seen similar behavior suggested that clearing the browser cache regularly can help.

I have this simple function that splits a comma-delimited string and uses the tokens to populate a Dojo data store:

```
UpdateFileNames: function(names) {
    var fileNames = names.split(",");
    var fileNameData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
        fileNameData.push({ name: fileNames[i], id: fileNames[i] });
    }
    this.fileListStore = new dojo.store.Memory({ data: fileNameData });
}
```

I'm stepping through this code in Firebug and can't believe what I'm seeing. Everything is happy until `i == fileNames.length`, at which point the loop is **entered again** and `fileNames[i]` is invalid.

What's going on here?

Comment: Please created a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo for your problem. But obviously if the body of the `for` loop is executed, the condition is fulfilled. So the data might not be what you think it is.

Comment: Is this your actual code, or have you attempted to simplify it?

Comment: What's the data coming in? I'm pretty sure `split()` works--does the list have a trailing comma?

Comment: @blo0p3r Splitting on commas will split on commas, spaces aren't relevant.

Comment: Have you lost interest in your own question? No response/clarification == Not A Real Question.

Comment: This is the actual code. split() works correctly, if I give it `"foo,bar"` then `fileNameData` is `[ "foo", "bar" ]`.

Comment: If that's the data, your loop works as expected.

Comment: @FelixKling The code is stepping into the body of the loop when `i == 2` and `fileNames.length == 2`, according to the debugger.

Comment: @TravisChristian: Forget the debugger. Are you saying that if you run your code without debugging, but you do `console.log(i === fileNames.length)` inside the loop, the last iteration will show `true` in the console?

Comment: ...and you wrote *"if I give it `"foo,bar"` then `fileNameData` is `[ "foo", "bar" ]`"*. But `fileNameData` is the new Array into which the data is pushed, so are you saying that it's actually working correctly?

Comment: @amnotiam Oops, I meant `fileNames` was `[ "foo", "bar" ]`.When I added `console.log(i)` before the push, it appears to have actually changed the behavior of the code. The loop is not entered an extra time, and the debugger is now hitting the final line where it was not hit before.

Comment: @TravisChristian: Seems like it may be a bug in Firebug rather than in the JavaScript environment. Try upgrading to the latest version if you haven't. If you can reproduce the bug using a simple example, it may be worth filing a bug report.

Comment: @amnotiam At this point it seems pretty clear that Firebug has been lying to me. Going back to the original code, I looked at the state of the object later on and `this.fileListStore` was created, and looks correct, after all. I guess this is a non-question.

Comment: @TravisChristian: Yeah, I tend to have a healthy distrust for debuggers. ;)

Comment: ...deleting my jsFiddle example because overriding `Array.prototype.push` just made a mess in the Chrome debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed to to loop one less?

```
for (var i = 0; i < fileNames.length-1; i++) {
    fileNameData.push({ name: fileNames[i], id: fileNames[i] });
}
```

If that works you need to look at how you generate your list (names). So that you dont get blank elements at the end.

Comment: Why would you want to skip the last filename?

Comment: I just meant as test case to see if the code worked then. Maybe the was a blank element at the end. This would be easier with an example of the list: names

Answer (score 0):

**Does `names` end with a comma?** If so, `fileNames[fileNames.length - 1] == ''`.

- [proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/kZvqw/)

Comment: No, there is no trailing comma and fileNames is composed as expected.